# problem im my key 3G "Connection activation failed" in 14.04

Tags: networking, 14.04, network-manager

I have a little problem in my Trusty. To beginn with, my mobile broadband works 100% but there is another connection that appears to be simultaneous.

```
/605020701514404/context1
```

When I click the new connection the following message appears: following

```
Connection activation failed
(1) Creating object for path '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1' failed in libnm-glib.
```

If I then click on `connection name` option of my key the following message appears:

```
Connection activation failed
(32) The connection was not supported by oFono.
```

When I want to create a new connection the `Create a connection for Mobile BroadBand` option contains two choices `empty any device`

Answer (score 4):

None of the above solutions worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04

The thing that worked:

1. Remove your broadband connection (right clicking Network applet > Edit Connections)
2. **Reboot**
3. Add connection again

This worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of restarting the machine. Restarting network-manager, which is actually causing the problem, solves the problem. Restart of network-manager forces all connections to be re-established.

Enter this command in a terminal:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

After you are prompted for and enter your password, this will restart the network manager.

Comment: I recommend expanding this answer (through editing) to explain why you expect restarting NetworkManager might fix the problem.